# Dealing with WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped when making a GET request with RestSharp

Tags: restsharp

I have a simple object:

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

that is being returned from a WCF service with the following Operational Contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/Countries/{aId}")]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Country")]
    Country Country(string aId);
```

Basically the object is wrapped inside a Country:{} block which is what I want. On the client side I do the following:

```
    private void RequestPrepare(out RestClient aRestClient, out RestRequest aRestRequest, string aRequestUri, Method aRequestMethod = Method.GET)
    {
        aRestClient = new RestClient(BASE_URL);
        aRestRequest = new RestRequest(aRequestUri, aRequestMethod);
        aRestRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    }
```

and call like so:

```
RestClient restClient;
RestRequest restRequest;

RequestPrepare(out restClient, out restRequest, "Countries/{aId}");
restRequest.AddUrlSegment("aId", "1"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource

var restResponse = restClient.Execute<Country>(restRequest);

List<Country> listCountry = new List<Country>();
listCountry.Add(new Country {Id = restResponse.Data.Id, Name = restResponse.Data.Name});
return listCountry;
```

the JSON response is:

```
Content = "{\"Country\":{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Australia\"}}"
```

so basically restResponse.Data.Id and  restResponse.Data.Name do not contain valid data because of the "Country" wrapping.

1) So how do I configure RestSharp to deal with the Country{} wrap?
2) As a secondary question how do I make the Restsharp call so that it will automatically deserialise List